# How to define static local variable in data section x86_64 Assembly Language (AT&T syntax)

Tags: assembly, static, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler

I am writing a assembly program to calculate the area and the circumference of a circle.

I defined `pi` in data section of two functions (`area` and `circum`). I want the specific `pi` (defined in the `data` section) to be visible only to that particular function. Basically I want a local static variable to a function.

```
.data

radius:
  .double   10.0

.text

.global main

main:
  pushq     %rbp
  movq      %rsp, %rbp

  call      circle

  movq      %rbp, %rsp
  popq      %rbp
  ret

.type       circle, @function
circle:

.data

.text
  pushq     %rbp
  movq      %rsp, %rbp

  # calculate the area of the circle
  call      area
  movl      $1, %eax
  movq      $fmtare, %rdi
  call      printf

  # calculate the circumference of the circle
  call      circum
  movl      $1, %eax
  movq      $fmtcir, %rdi
  call      printf

  movq      %rbp, %rsp
  popq      %rbp
  ret

.type       area, @function
area:

.data
pi:
  .double   3.14

.text
  pushq     %rbp
  movq      %rsp, %rbp

  movsd     pi, %xmm0
  mulsd     radius, %xmm0
  mulsd     radius, %xmm0

  movq      %rbp, %rsp
  popq      %rbp
  ret

.type       circum, @function
circum:

.data
pi:
  .double   3.141592

.text
  pushq     %rbp
  movq      %rsp, %rbp

  movsd     radius, %xmm0
  addsd     radius, %xmm0
  mulsd     pi, %xmm0

  movq      %rbp, %rsp
  popq      %rbp
  ret


fmtare:
  .asciz    "The area is %g\n"

fmtcir:
  .asciz    "The circumference is %g\n"
```

Comment: The GNU assembler does not have the notion of a function.  It does not support scopes either.  What you want is not truly achievable.

Comment: Just like how C compilers do it under the hood, by naming conventions for the symbols.  e.g. `foo_var1:` or even `foo.var1:`  (The `.` isn't special in asm symbol names, but it makes it extra hard to access the variable from C).
`.data` is one contiguous section, even if you switch back and forth to emitting bytes into it at various places in your source code.  And the namespace for labels is file scope, no way to narrow it more in GAS.  In NASM there's stuff like `foo:` / `.var1:` which is like `foo.var1:` - https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9

Comment: Put the function and its data alone in the same file with no other code, and be sure not to mark the variable .global.  Then  no-one will be able to see or link to that name.  Though as already said, the storage is not protected, just the name not bind-able.